# PHP Session Not working and not giving any error

Tags: php, session

In My login.php I have

```
<?php 

require_once('connection.php');
$loginErr = "";
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
  $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
  $run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);
  $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
  if($check_user>0){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header('Location: '.'index.php');
  }
  else {
    $loginErr = "Email or password is not correct, try again!";
  }
}
?>
```

Basically if username and password matches it creates session "email" and redirects to index page.

In my navbar which is common to all pages like index and other. I have

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
 <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>    
<li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>    
<?php } else { ?>
<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>   
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Basically if there is no session email then login and logout is shown and if session email is set then logout is shown.

**But Its always showing login and register button even if user is logged in or logged out.**

My logout Page

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset($_SESSION['email']);
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

I am trying to show logout button when user is logged in and login, register button when not. But I am not able to find the error in my code and it doesn't give any error. its just showing login register button always.

Thanks.

Edit 1:

Forgot to mention Session start is in connection.php file

**Edit 2:**

**session_start(); I have put on first line of login page and homepage but same problem**

**Edit 3:
When I var dump session after session set I get session value of email but when I var dump in homepage I get  Undefined index: email**

Comment: did you start session on connection.php?

Comment: Yes session is started on connection.php

Comment: try below code. at logout.php

Comment: yes I did. still same result as its not showing logout page I cant click logout

Comment: check you client session timeout int he F12

Comment: in your code, you have session email and session user_email, are they not the same???

Comment: header('Location: '.'index.php'); change it..

Comment: checkout var_dump the $_SESSION in the logout page

Comment: I did var dumb after setting session in login and its working: string 'r@d.com'. but idk whats wrong in homepage

Comment: in homepage var dump i get  Undefined index: email

Comment: Please see my edit 3:

Answer (score 0):

You have to `start_Session();` in `connection.php`. Or you can start here like this...

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');
$loginErr = "";
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
  $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
  $run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);
  $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
  if($check_user>0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header('Location:index.php');
  }
  else {
    $loginErr = "Email or password is not correct, try again!";
  }
}
?>
```

And your `logout.php` must be like this...

```
<?php
//session_start();  no need to start here
session_unset($_SESSION['email']);
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Does not start_session at home page.Because session is always started at once. And try following code.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>  
<?php } else { ?>
<li><a href="login">Login</a></li>    
<li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>    
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: session is started on connection.php

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: everything is fine... did u make changes referred above?

Comment: yes I made changes. removed session_start from logout and added session_start in login. but still same problem

Comment: Now Logout is showing but now when I click logout it still shows logout.